# I have a java String that I am writing to disk and I want to check before I write it how much space it will ocupy

Tags: java, xml, string, base64

I have an XML that I get data from (API) and I fill variables with that data.
One of those variables contains base64 and I need to write a file that contains that text. How can I check before I write to file what space the `String` will occupy so I can limit it?

Thanks

Comment: The text would be the length of the base64 `String`, there are 6-bits per character in that `String` (minus any trailing padding character). From the [Base64 Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) *The term Base64 originates from a specific MIME content transfer encoding. Each Base64 digit represents exactly 6 bits of data. Three 8-bit bytes (i.e., a total of 24 bits) can therefore be represented by four 6-bit Base64 digits.*

Comment: What do you mean by how much space it will occupy exactly? The char count of the String or the byte size of it or what?

Comment: I mean byte size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a Base64 string only contains ASCII characters, the string will occupy as many bytes and it has characters, i.e. `s.length()`, regardless of character set.

Unless you save the file in UTF-16 (double the size) or UTF-32 (quadruple the size) or some other multi-byte characters set, but that's rare.